# Mysql error: 1222 when I am creating a new table from two existing tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1222

Mysql error: 1222 when I am creating a new table from two existing tables.
This is my sql statement for creating a new table from two existing table. Please help me to find solution for this problem, Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE insurance_db.new_insurance 
SELECT * FROM insurance_db.auto_insurance
UNION all
SELECT * FROM insurance_db.home_insurance;
```

Comment: Can you show the create statement of `insurance_db.auto_insurance` and `insurance_db.home_insurance`? looks like they have a different numbe of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
CREATE TABLE insurance_db.new_insurance 
As (SELECT col1, col2,.... FROM insurance_db.auto_insurance, insurance_db.home_insurance);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you trying to unite `SELECT`s with different count of columns.

For example:

```
SELECT 1     -- one column
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2  -- two colums
```

Causes this error:

```
Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

Try to use determined columnt-list for both selects:

```
CREATE TABLE insurance_db.new_insurance 
SELECT
    col1, col2, col3 ...
FROM
    insurance_db.auto_insurance
UNION ALL
SELECT
    col1, col2, col3 ...
FROM
    insurance_db.home_insurance;
```